# Use X-Forwarded-Host in server_name for nginx

Tags: nginx

How can I re-use the `X-Forwarded-Host` variable as an argument for `server_name` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Sorry. Server names are used to construct a hash table at the nginx startup, where lookups for the required server block according to the `Host` header value will be made with the `O(1)` complexity time. Server names specified by regex patterns is a different story, those regex patterns will be matched upon the `Host` header value if the hash-based table lookup would fail. However you can't use variables in regex patterns too, all regex patterns are being compiled at the nginx startup. If you describe the task you are trying to solve, maybe I can suggest you some other way to solve it.

Comment: Well the the URL that is passed to our nginx is transformed in local path where the domain is removed. The only way to retrieve the actual domain is from the X-FORWARDED-HOST header.